# inner join inside a foreach loop?

Tags: php, oop, pdo, foreach

**Story:** 
I want to create thumbnails for all the products I have in the database, this, by creating a foreach loop I managed to fetch all data, but.. a `product` has a relationship with a `file`, an image to be exact and this image has a `file_url`, to obtain the `file_url` from the table `file` I have to create an INNER JOIN by grabbing the `file_id` from the `products` table ON `file`.`file_url`.

**My code**

```
/**
 * @var array Collection of error messages
 */
$warnings = array();


    //  Constants from db.php in variable
    $dbhost = DB_HOST;
    $dbuser = DB_USER;
    $dbpass = DB_PASS;
    $dbname = DB_NAME;

    //  Try to connect to PDO first
    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);

        $conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT );
        $conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING );
        $conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        die($warnings[] =  $e->getMessage());
    }

// Select all products
$query = "SELECT * FROM product";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();

foreach($result as $product)
    {
        $file_id = $product['file_id'];

        $select_image_query = "SELECT `file`.`file_url` ";
        $select_image_query .= "FROM `file` ";
        $select_image_query .= "INNER JOIN `product` ON `file`.`file_id` = `product`.`file_id` ";
        $select_image_query .= "WHERE `product`.`file_id` = :file_id";

        $stmt_select = $conn->prepare($select_image_query);
        $stmt_select->bindParam(':file_id', $file_id, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
        $stmt_select->execute();
        $stmt_select->bindColumn('file_url', $file_url);


    //  Product thumbnail image
        echo "<img class=\"group list-group-image\" src=\"" . $file_url . "\" alt=\"\" />";

           #code .. .. 

          $stmt_select = null;
    }
```

**Question:**
At this point I am curious about the consequences. Is this the right way to obtain the `file_url` within the foreach loop? How can I obtain the `file_url` for each product seperately?

I really appreciate criticism and other people's view so I can learn, please point it out if you see something! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop is pointless. You fetch a list of all the product IDs, then use that list to fetch the rest of the exact same records. Why not just

```
SELECT product_id, file_id, file_url
FROM file
INNER JOIN product ON file.file_id = product.file_id
```

for the query?

However, kudos for using the prepared statement and placeholder, even if they weren't necessary.

And note, as a further tip, you don't need to continually re-prepare the query each time. That's the whole point of prepared statements. you prepare them ONCE, then execut over and over with different values for the placeholders. Your code should have been

```
$stmt = prepare...
... bind ...
while(...) {
    $value_for_query = ...;
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->fetch();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
* @var array Collection of error messages
*/
$warnings = array();

//  Constants from db.php in variable
$dbhost = DB_HOST;
$dbuser = DB_USER;
$dbpass = DB_PASS;
$dbname = DB_NAME;

//  Try to connect to PDO first
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);

    $conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT );
    $conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING );
    $conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    die($warnings[] =  $e->getMessage());
}
$strSql = "SELECT * FROM product "
        . "LEFT JOIN file ON `file`.`file_id` = `product`.`file_id` ";
$listProducts = $conn->query($strSql)->fetchAll();

foreach($listProducts as $arrProduct)
{            
    if (!empty($arrProduct['file_url'])) {
        //  Product thumbnail image
        echo "<img class=\"group list-group-image\" src=\"" . $arrProduct['file_url'] . "\" alt=\"\" />";
    }
    #code .. .. 
}
```

Comment: Hello Dzinya, Thanks for your answer. Could you explain the reason why you have chosen for  the left join?

Comment: because if in file-table not exist row for product,  selected products were not all, if use inner join